# iloc and loc are not working when applying function to multiple columns,

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Assume this is my `df` and dtypes are `int64` at the beginning.

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   5   6   7
2   8   9   10
3   13  14  15
```

Then I tried to convert all the values to astype `str` using

```
df = df.astype(str)
df.dtypes

A    int64
B    int64
C    int64
dtype: object
```

Now it changed the dtypes to `object` like I expected. Now I tried to convert few columns to dtype `int64` again using `pd.to_numeric` with `apply` function

```
df.iloc[:, 0:2] = df.iloc[:, 0:2].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
print(df.dtypes)
A    object
B    object
C    object
dtype: object
```

This above code was executed but it didn't change the dtypes of col `A and B` to `int64`. They are still dtype `object`. I can't understand why it didn't work.

I even tried the same code with `loc` rather than `iloc` but it still doesn't work the dtypes are still `object`

```
df.loc[:, ['A','B']] = df.loc[:, ['A','B']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

But when I use only `df[[cols]]` it works.

```
df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') # This works
```

Note : I have searched but couldn't find anything related to my question. If this is a duplicate question please point me towards it.

Comment: I would say it's a bug.

Comment: I can just add that the problem is not that `iloc` and `loc` doesn't "change" the `dtype` as is implied in the question. `df[['A', 'B']] = df.iloc[:,0:2].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` would update the `dtype` correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: unable to change column data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778139/pandas-unable-to-change-column-data-type)